Add newlines before selected hyphen symbols
I have such a pattern in my text:

PSA-image report on
-15.12.1402 (05.03.2024): 0.15 ng/ml
-19.04.1403 (09.07.2024): 0.36ng/ml.

And I have the above text as a one line string:
let string = `PSA-report on -15.12.1402 (05.03.2024): 0.15 ng/ml -19.04.1403 (09.07.2024): 0.36ng/ml.`

I want to convert the string from the one line format to the format you see in the pattern. I want to insert a newline before every hyphen which has a number directly after it.
I tried this code ...
string = string.replaceAll('-', '\n-');

... but it adds a newline before every hyphen. How do I match just the ones which are directly followed by a number?


let string = `PSA-report on -15.12.1402 (05.03.2024): 0.15 ng/ml -19.04.1403 (09.07.2024): 0.36ng/ml.`
string = string.replaceAll('-', '\n-');
console.log(string);




Can you describe the requirements? Currently, it looks like the code solve the problem for the example input.

string = string.replaceAll(/(-[0-9]+)/g, '\n$1'); ...?

Use a positive lookahead to detect the presence of a digit following the hyphen.


let string = `PSA-report on -15.12.1402 (05.03.2024): 0.15 ng/ml -19.04.1403 (09.07.2024): 0.36ng/ml.`
string = string.replaceAll(/-(?=\d)/g, '\n-');
console.log(string);



You can find more information at regex101.

You can move the - inside of the lookahead and remove the - from the substitution to keep it clean.

@HaoWu good idea. Why not undelete your answer?

@mplungjan I wasn't sure this is OP's desired answer, since their code is a little bit confusing

I agree that moving the - inside the lookahead is another solution which works, but I find it a little harder to follow what is going on. My guess is that for an average programmer trying to read this code, my version would be easier to understand. In my expression, it's clear that I'm looking for a hyphen followed by a digit, and replacing it with a newline followed by a hyphen. It makes sense to my way of thinking, anyway.

You could try
string.replace(/(?=-\d)/g, '\n')



let string = `PSA-report on -15.12.1402 (05.03.2024): 0.15 ng/ml -19.04.1403 (09.07.2024): 0.36ng/ml.`

const formatted = string.replace(/(?=-\d)/g, '\n');

console.log(formatted);




You can match a hyphen and a digit, and in the replacement use a newline followed by the match.
-\d

In the replacement use \n$&
See a regex demo


let string = `PSA-report on -15.12.1402 (05.03.2024): 0.15 ng/ml -19.04.1403 (09.07.2024): 0.36ng/ml.`

console.log(string.replace(/-\d/g, '\n$&'));



